# How do you unit test (mocha) Vuex actions that rely on state, commit, dispatch, and getters?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, mocha.js, chai, vuex

I've got a pretty complex Vuex action that I need to test - one that needs access not only to {commit}, but to the whole shebang - {commit, dispatch, state, getters}.

I want to test actions.getTotals() here.  How would you go about this in a Mocha/Chai based framework?

Keep in mind that I don't have to mock anything from the API - I will be testing against a local database.

```
const actions = {
  getTotals: ({ commit, getters, state, dispatch }, metadata) => {
    dispatch('startTimer')
    return api.totals({
      dateFrom: getters.startDate,
      dateTo: getters.endDate,
      clientId: state.filters.client.id,
      metadata: metadata
    })
    .then((response) => commit(types.UPDATE_TOTALS, response.data.result))
    .then(() => dispatch('stopTimer'))
  },
  startTimer: ({commit}) => commit('START_TIMER', Date.now()),
  stopTimer: ({commit}) => commit('STOP_TIMER', Date.now())
}
```